# Progressive Image Loading Technique

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, image-processing

When i am searching image through Google [Link to view](https://www.google.com.np/search?q=kantipur%20font%20preview&rlz=1C1CHWA_enNP528NP528&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=V5gVUp3zDojLrQe2y4G4Aw&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1280&bih=923#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=YGUEfl21Wj9ikM:;IpKnhrmfUQ1shM;http%253A%252F%252Ffc05.deviantart.net%252Ffs71%252Fi%252F2011%252F135%252Fb%252F5%252Fnepali_keyboard_fingering_by_lalitkala-d3ggmg3.jpg;http%253A%252F%252Flalitkala.deviantart.com%252Fart%252FNepali-keyboard-fingering-209047971;1280;1024) 
it load blur image first then load high-quality image progressively as image below

[image]

after some time

[image]

but by inspecting that image i found [This Link](http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2011/135/b/5/nepali_keyboard_fingering_by_lalitkala-d3ggmg3.jpg) and by going that link it load complete image or loaded image is viewed as top to down preview as below picture.

[image]

how it happened?
what technique Google use for Progressive loading of image.
how can i do loading of image as Google do in my site? 
is it possible using c# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that there is no actual progressive loading going on in Google Images.

When you click on an image thumbnail, there is a quick animation "unveiling" the full resolution image. While the animation is happening, the image that is partly displayed is actually just the thumbnail (size 251x201), but upscaled to the resolution of the larger image (1280X1024).

The way to do this upscaling in HTML should be something like this:

```
<img src="thumbnail.jpg" width="251" height="201">
```

The full resolution image is then displayed when the animation is completed, replacing the upscaled thumbnail. So this is not a progressive loading after all.

Still, you might want to read about Progressive JPEG: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_compression.